# How to update multiple values using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first

As an example,

```
Table 1 (School class)
- Id (int)
- Countries represented (List<Country>)

Table 2 (country)
- Id (int)
- Name (string)
```

So a school class can contain 1 or several countries. These countries then gets updated based on where the students are from.

```
void UpdateSchoolClass(int id, List<int> countryIds)
{
    // So here i got a list of country ids (that matches table 2 countries). The list is from a multiple select list on a html-page.

    var schoolClass = dbContext.SchoolClasses.First(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    var countriesSelected = dbContext.Countries.Where(x => countryIds.Contains(x.Id));

    // How can i now make sure that only the countries that were selected in the list is added to the school class countries list? 
    // It might be that when i did an update, 1 or more countries have been deleted or added. 
    // I need to make sure that if it's not selected but was in the database before then it should be removed. Likewise that new selections should be added.

    // One way would be to just delete all country entries, save the entity and then re-add all entries that are selected. Are there other ways that this, easily, can be resolved with using LINQ to SQL?
    // Is this the preferred way or is there a better way?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best bet in this situation is to [execute sql command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Linq to SQL can not remove country from school without selecting it first.

I mean there is always a possibility that someone else has added new country to the school between your select and update. You can detect these changes using concurrency checks (timestamp or rowversion in SQL server) and try repeating this operation untill it is successful.